# Xtext assign values during parsing

Tags: xtext

I'm trying to build a parser that can take a human language expression like `twenty five percent` and transform it into a number like `25%`.

Essentially I have a rule like this:

```
Number:
    (T1 | T2 | T3 T1) 'percent'?
;

terminal T1: 'zero' | 'one' | 'two' etc....;
terminal T2: 'ten' | 'eleven' | 'twelve' etc...;
terminal T3: 'twenty' | 'thirty' | 'forty' etc...;
```

And I want to transform it somehow so that when I access `Number` in Xtend to generate my code it will not be text like `twenty five percent` but it will be a number.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please be more specific. What did you try to do? Parsing 'twenty five percent' as 25% is certainly possible but the question is to broad to answer it probably, e.g. what do you mean by the given 'rule' which is certainly not a rule in the sense of Xtext, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined Number as a data type rule that returns a String.

If you use something like

```
Number returns ecore::EBigDecimal:
  (T1 | T2 | T3 T1) 'percent'?
;
```

you can define a value converter for your rule `Number` and convert it to an actual instance of `BigDecimal`. The callee of the rule Number will see it as a `BigDecimal`. Please refer to the [docs](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#valueconverter) for details on value conversion in Xtext. Please keep in mind that you have to import the Ecore package for that purpose. Take a look at the common terminals and the docs if you have questions about that.

Comment: Just for reference, I found this to be useful [Custom terminals in Xtext](http://xtextcasts.org/episodes/11-custom-terminals)